# How to add Postgres to Alibaba Cloud

Tags: postgresql, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I have ECS at Alibaba cloud, I want to add PostgreSQL, but I can't find any Tutorials on the Internet
how to add PostgreSQL to ECS Alibaba Cloud

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways on using PostgreSQL on Alibaba Cloud:

- [**ApsaraDB RDS for PostgreSQL**](https://www.alibabacloud.com/product/apsaradb-for-rds-postgresql), which is PaaS solution for PostgreSQL on Alibaba Cloud, so you don't have to worry about installing and configuring PostgreSQL from scratch. It comes with a lot of additional features such as, high availability, disaster recovery, backup, etc. You can find their [documentation on creating your PostgreSQL instance](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/53730.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.879954.5.74c055b1GaC1Qj#t7846.html).
- [**ApsaraDB for PolarDB**](https://www.alibabacloud.com/product/polardb?spm=a3c0i.247269.9942033750.2.10ed6959knAbKg), also a PaaS, which is Alibaba Cloud's homegrown RDB fully compatible with MySQL and PostgreSQL. It can support higher storage capacity, nodes clustering, and it's designed for high performance. Check out their [documentation on how to create a PostgreSQL cluster](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/118063.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.879954.3.648155b1iVBZOj).
- **Self-managed PostgreSQL on ECS** - of cause you can still run PostgreSQL on your own ECS. There're plenty of resources on how to install and configure your own PostgreSQL. Check out the DigitalOcean's tutorial on [installing PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-postgresql-on-ubuntu-20-04-quickstart).

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to do it.

1. you would just take the ECS as a Linux server. you build the PostgreSQL by yourself. it may request higher skills.
2. you would use the PaaS service, polardb(PostgreSQL) ,you do not need build it step by step ,just use it in 2-3 mins.

the polardb links as below:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/product/polardb?spm=a3c0i.20899616.6791778070.dbannerarelationaldb1.53fd2accf4slGC